# xcode core data cascading delete not working within table view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have the following **data model** with defined **cascading delete**, but if I delete a row from the ***entity Record*** within the **table view** the corresponding records in the ***Puls entity*** are not deleted. I can not figure out why.

[image]

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    {

        [tableView beginUpdates];
        // Delete the row from the data source

        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

        [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:[self.fetchedRecordsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

        NSError *error;
        if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Whoops, couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }

        tpAppDelegate* appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
        self.fetchedRecordsArray = [appDelegate getAllRecords];

        [tableView endUpdates];
    }
}


-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    tpAppDelegate* appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    self.managedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext;

    // Fetching Records and saving it in "fetchedRecordsArray" object
    self.fetchedRecordsArray = [[appDelegate  getAllRecords]mutableCopy];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    tpAppDelegate* appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    self.managedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext;

    self.fetchedRecordsArray = [[appDelegate  getAllRecords]mutableCopy];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: No error then? How are you testing for the objects before and after the delete?

Comment: No I get no errors. I am using the app "iExplorer" to copy the Document folder of my app from the iPhone to my MAC and than I open the .sqlite file with an other app "SQLPro for SQLite" where I can see all data.

Comment: Try querying the context, you shouldn't really look at the underlying files. I'm not saying something isn't wrong, but ask the SDK if it is rather than asking the private data store.

Comment: Is the managed object context used in the delete the same one that is beeing used when fetching the record array?

Comment: Some side advice... While it's not recommended by many, I've learned to query my Core Data created SQLite files during using Terminal. If you find the location of your SQLite files, keep a copy of the path in Notes so you can quickly copy and paste that into then command line. Then learn enough terminal commands to change directory `cd` etc, and enough sqlite3 commands to access and query your data stores.

Answer (score 1):

You need to commit your changes by saving the managed object context if you want them to be persisted. Remember that if you have a child managed object context saving will only propagate the changes to the parent managed object context.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSManagedObjectContext/deletedObjects
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSManagedObjectContext/save:

Comment: I thought with the save statement I am committing the db operation. (apple doc: save: Attempts to commit unsaved changes to registered objects to the receiver’s parent store.)

Comment: If the managed object store is the top store it will persist the change to your db, otherwise it will only update the parent manager object store. "If a context’s parent store is a persistent store coordinator, then changes are committed to the external store. If a context’s parent store is another managed object context, then save: only updates managed objects in that parent store. To commit changes to the external store, you must save changes in the chain of contexts up to and including the context whose parent is the persistent store coordinator."

Comment: Hi Erik, I added the viewDidLoad and viewWillAppear to my original question to show how I setup things. Unfortunately I do not understand what you are writing my knowledge regarding managed object is poor. Would you please be so kind and show me which code I have to add to my source code to let the cascading delete fire?

Answer (score -1):

Try taking this row...

```
 [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:[self.fetchedRecordsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

Out of your `if` statement in your `tableView:commitEditingStyle` method.

---

Actually realised my previous advice above is not going to work, as you need to check for `UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete`

I'll think on it but apologies have nothing else to suggest at this stage.

Comment: If I remove that statement I get an error: 
2015-04-14 21:48:50.035 ....[671:11860] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (1) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (1), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).

Comment: Apologies I should be more clear. See updated answer.